# Query to sum amounts from one table and group it by a column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have the two tables as shown, `crime_charges` and `crimes`, that are from a `Crime` database. I need to show the total amount of fines owed (`fine_amount + court_fee`) but it must be grouped by the classification (F, M or O).

[image: crime and crime_charges tables]

I tried the following query but I'm getting stuck on the error shown below:

```
SELECT
    (fine_amount + court_fee) as [Total Fines Owed]
FROM
    crime_charges
INNER JOIN
    crimes on crimes.crime_id = crime_charges.crime_id
GROUP BY
    classification;
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 74
> Column 'crime_charges.court_fee' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Use a SUM() function. The `Group By` is used when dealing with aggregate functions. But you're not using any of those, because you use the `+` operator to do the aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to sum the fine amount plus court fees:

```
select classification, sum(fine_amount+court_fee) as [Total Fines Owed]
from crime_charges cc
inner join crimes c on c.crime_id = cc.crime_id
group by classification;
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped!  So I guess the values that need to be added MUST be in a function of some sort (like SUM function) in order to be considered valid?

Comment: @dheeke1 The moment you say `GROUP BY classification`, it only makes sense to select aggregates of the records in each group, such as the sum of values.  Selecting individual record values makes no sense, as it is no longer clear to the database _which_ record's value you want.